# Expected value approximation in the discrete case

Tags: probability, expected-value

In Bishop's book, page 20, the following assumption is made:

Defining the expectation value of a function under some probability distribution as

$$\mathbb E[f] = \sum_x p(x)f(x)$$

if we take a finite number, N, of points $x_n$ from $p(x)$, the following approximation can be made

$$\mathbb E[f] \approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_n f(x_n).$$

In order for this to happen $p(x_n) \approx 1/N^2$ for all $x_n$, but what is the reasoning behind this approximation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim \ \text{iid} \ p$. Then 
$$
 \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i) \to_p E_p(f(X_1))
$$
under very mild regularity conditions, where $\to_p$ denotes convergence in probability and $E_p$ denotes expectation with respect to $p$. This is the law of large numbers.

Note that
$$
\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i) \frac1n 
$$

so if we have a pmf $\hat p$ that puts a mass of $1/n$ at each individual observation $x_i$ (*not* each unique value: in the case of duplicates we will have a mass $> \frac1n$) then this is the expectation with respect to this empirical distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for pointing out my mistake. So in order for $p(x)$ to put a mass of $1/n$ on each observed point, is this equivalent to saying that this distribution p is uniform?

Comment: Yes, our empirical distribution $\hat p$ is uniform over the observed values. The actual generating distribution $p$ is not necessarily uniform.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thank you once more. One last question; in the case where $N\rightarrow \infty$ how does this approximation turn exact, as stated in the book?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to look at that but here are two that I find helpful. First of all, by the LLN we know that the sample mean converges to the true mean. Secondly, $\hat p$ is the derivative of the empirical CDF, and as $N \to \infty$ the empirical CDF $\hat F_N \to F$, the real CDF, so an expectation with respect to $\hat F$ becomes in the limit one with respect to $F$, i.e. the true mean.

Comment: That makes sense, it all ends up hinging on the LLN as we are just calculating expectation values. Thank you.

Comment: you're very welcome.

Comment: There may be some terminological confusion here.  When the underlying distribution is discrete and $n$ is large enough, there will be ties in the data.  The resulting empirical distribution is then *not* going to be "uniform over the observed values."  Indeed, your whole point is that the empirical distribution will tend to approximate the underlying distribution.  I suspect you might have meant that the empirical distribution is uniform over the *individual observations* rather than over their *values.*

Comment: @whuber good point. In the actual answer I indexed $i = 1, \dots, n$ to avoid having to deal with the duplicate issue but my comment was not clear.